# mac cann't use Shortcut key by root after set in .bash_profile

Tags: bash, macos

I use  MacOS ,I had set Shortcut-key for apps on my account，but when I want to use the Shortcut-key by root account , it doesn't work ,why?

I set the Shortcut-key in the `.bash_profile` just like follow:

```
alias subl="'/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'"
alias pycharm="'/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/MacOS/pycharm'"
```

On my account as hs ,it worked like follow:

[Shortcut-key work with my account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibJPt.png)

but when I use root account ,it doesn't work ,just like :

[Shortcut-key doesn't work with root account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzvA9.png)

How can I set Shortcut-key ,can it work on both my account and root account ?thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type `alias` as `root user` to list all available aliases for root.  Make sure `alias subl` is available if not there.

your ~/.bash_profile will have no effect after you switch to `root user`. You may `source /Users/<your non-root username>/.bash_profile` to use the aliases defined there.

Comment: Thanks so much, I will try it as you said , thanks a lot!

Comment: An alternative to aliases would be to create symlinks in `/usr/local/bin`. Those are automatically available for all users of the system. Create them like this `sudo ln -s /path/to/utility /usr/local/bin/utility`